# HBase Indexer + Solr

Tags: solr, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm trying to integrate HBase with Solr. Everything seems to work, Hbase indexer communicates with zookeeper on a different HBase Machine. But rows I put into Hbase are notr created under Solr.

- HBase version: 1.1.2.2.5.5.0-157 (Hortonworks)
- Solr : 5.2.1 (LucidWorks)
  Tested Hbase Indexer : 
  Hbase-indexer :  default version, compiled with ( mvn clean install -DskipTests -Dhbase.api=1.1)

Everytime I start the HBase Indexer Server, I got this exception:

```
17/06/16 19:02:43 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server sr1/172.20.21.15:2181, sessionid = 0x15cb1081862007e, negotiated timeout = 40000
17/06/16 19:02:44 INFO zookeeper.LeaderElection: Elected as leader for the position of Indexer Master
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient
        at com.ngdata.hbaseindexer.master.IndexerMaster.getJobClient(IndexerMaster.java:181)
        at com.ngdata.hbaseindexer.master.IndexerMaster.start(IndexerMaster.java:144)
        at com.ngdata.hbaseindexer.Main.startServices(Main.java:124)
        at com.ngdata.hbaseindexer.Main.run(Main.java:96)
        at com.ngdata.hbaseindexer.Main.main(Main.java:84)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 5 more
```

Does anybody know how to deal with this jar conflict problem?

Comment: Did you check it via mvn dependency tree?

Comment: Thanks Kamaci.
Actually, I'm using the HDP 2.5 with Solr(LucidWorks) 5.2. It seems that I must install Solr 5.5 as recommended in HortonWorks docs.
Will give it a try and update this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was a Solr version problem. It should be 5.5 at least to use HBase 1.1.2.